# SQL Server XML Date Import

Tags: sql, xml, date

Having trouble importing an xml date feild into sql server, the other feilds are fine. I have tried numerous way's but it always returns as null. Any help please

2014-02-18T12:15:21.357 is the issue

The XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MISRoot xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/IGUK.Evolution.FieldToolLite.Lib.MIS">
    <Claims>
        <Claim>
            <Amalgamation>
                <ChannelSolutions /> 
                <Name i:nil="true" /> 
            </Amalgamation>
            <Appointments>
                <Appointment>
                    <Access /> 
                    <AccessGranted>true</AccessGranted> 
                    <AppointmentId>320</AppointmentId> 
                    <EnterTime>2014-02-18T12:15:21.357</EnterTime> 
                    <LeaveTime i:nil="true" /> 
                    <Name i:nil="true" /> 
                </Appointment>
            </Appointments>
            <CustomProducts /> 
            <Id>1220</Id> 
            <Payments /> 
            <Tasks /> 
        </Claim>
    </Claims>
</MISRoot>
```

THE SQL is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[xmlImportAppointments](
  [ClaimId] [int] not null,
  [AppointmentAUTO] [int] not NULL,
  [AppointmentId] [int] not NULL,
  [EnterTime] [datetime] NULL,
  [LeaveTime] [datetime] NULL,
  [AccessGranted] [nchar](20) NULL,
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/IGUK.Evolution.FieldToolLite.Lib.MIS')
INSERT INTO xmlImportAppointments
  (ClaimId, AppointmentAUTO, AppointmentId, EnterTime, LeaveTime, AccessGranted)
SELECT 
    ClaimId = xmldata.value('(Claim/Id)[1]', 'int'),
    AppointmentAUTO = xmldata.value('(Claim/Appointments/Appointment/AppointmentId)[1]', 'int'),
    AppointmentId = xmldata.value('(Claim/Appointments/Appointment/AppointmentId)[1]', 'int'),
    EnterTime = xmldata.value('(Claims/Appointment/Appointments/EnterTime)[1]', 'datetime'),
    LeaveTime = xmldata.value('(Claims/Appointment/Appointments/EnterTime)[1]', 'datetime'), 
    AccessGranted = xmldata.value('(Claim/Appointments/Appointment/AccessGranted)[1]', 'NCHAR(20)')
FROM 
    (SELECT CAST(x AS XML)
     FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '\\XMLTest\increment.xml',
     SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)) AS T(x)
CROSS APPLY 
    x.nodes('/MISRoot/Claims') AS X(xmldata);

SELECT * FROM xmlImportAppointments
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a problem with your `XQuery` I had copied your File into a `XML` variable and was able to retrieve using the following query.

```
DECLARE @MyXMLVariable XML = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MISRoot xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/IGUK.Evolution.FieldToolLite.Lib.MIS">
    <Claims>
        <Claim>
        <Amalgamation>
            <ChannelSolutions /> 
            <Name i:nil="true" /> 
        </Amalgamation>
        <Appointments>
            <Appointment>
                <Access /> 
                <AccessGranted>true</AccessGranted> 
                <AppointmentId>320</AppointmentId> 
                <EnterTime>2014-02-18T12:15:21.357</EnterTime> 
                <LeaveTime i:nil="true" /> 
                <Name i:nil="true" /> 
            </Appointment>
        </Appointments>
        <CustomProducts /> 
        <Id>1220</Id> 
        <Payments /> 
        <Tasks /> 
        </Claim>
    </Claims>
</MISRoot>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/IGUK.Evolution.FieldToolLite.Lib.MIS')
SELECT @MyXMLVariable.value('(MISRoot/Claims/Claim/Appointments/Appointment/EnterTime)[1]','DATETIME')
```

You did not specify the full correct path to `EnterTime`

```
'(MISRoot/Claims/Claim/Appointments/Appointment/EnterTime)[1]' --Correct
'(Claims/Appointment/Appointments/EnterTime)[1]' --Yours
```

`Appointment` is child of `Appointments` not the other way around and `Claim` is a child of `Claims` best way to do this is to look at Open tags and closed tags

Comment: Thanks, really didn't spot that!!